# extract string before/after character without this character in r

Tags: r, stringr

I have a strings that look like that:

```
strings <- c("100% 16 Feedback Kakkanad, Ernakulam","98% 159 Feedback Greater Kailash Part 1, Delhi","Bannerghatta Road, Bangalore ₹250 Available on Su")
```

I want to extract number of feedbacks using stringr. After some tries I almost got it.

```
stringr
str_extract_all(strings,"\\%.*[0-9]\\s", simplify = T)
```

Function above returns vector:

```
"% 16 ", "% 159 ",""
```

I would like to extract only this number, so remove % and white spaces. I tried to search, but I didn't know how to define my problem in fewer words :(

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` with a regex lookaround to extract the digits that follow any zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by the string 'Feedback'

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(c(str_extract_all(strings, "\\d+(?=\\s*Feedback)", simplify = TRUE)))
#[1]  16 159
```

---

The issue with matching the `%` is that it also become part of the output.  Instead, it can be a regex lookaround

```
as.numeric(str_extract_all(strings,"(?<=\\%\\s)[0-9]+", simplify = TRUE))
#[1]  16 159
```

Comment: Thanks, for quick answer!